# Where can I purchase extra wood pieces for Settlers of Catan?

Tags: catan

I have two full sets of Settlers of Catan plus one 5-6 player expansion pack. Originally the second set was bought to replace the older one, which was missing a few pieces and cards.  However, the epicness of the possibility of a huge SoC game entranced me, and I decided to use all three game sets to make one very large game. By cutting three frame pieces, I was able to craft a 48-hex island, suitable for up to 10 players. (Apologies for the cell-phoneness of the photo.)

[image]

So now I have two sets each of blue, orange, white, and red wooden pieces, and one set each of green and brown.  By marking half the double sets (dots with a Sharpie), it is possible to differentiate one half of each double color from the other, resulting in ten sets. Sets can also be combined for fewer players.  The development and resource cards which were missing were minimal, so that's not an issue.  But sometimes the wooden pieces pose a problem.  Sometimes, with four players, the green and brown sets are used as backup pieces for the remaining four double sets which are missing a few.  But if I ever want to play with 10 players, I'll have to come up with substitutions, which I'd like to avoid.  Where can I find extra wooden pieces for the original Settlers of Catan?

Comment: I'm assuming you would like to do this without buying yet another game? :)

Comment: Also, I bet monopolies would cause an instant win in a 10 player game!!

Comment: Have you tried ebay or amazon?

Comment: @corsiKa Yeah, I might decide to change the rules a bit if we ever get into an actual 10-player game. :)

Comment: @DanielPalamarchuk Actually, yes.  But I'd like to avoid paying [$9 for each 24-piece set](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SETTLERS-OF-CATAN-Cities-Roads-Settlements-BLUE-24-Replacement-Parts-NEW-/400371638247?pt=Games_US&hash=item5d38025fe7) if possible.  It'd end up being almost less expensive to buy a whole new set.  And Amazon doesn't seem to hold SoC wood pieces alone.

Comment: Wow, just wow... I tried something like this in a two player game (first to 30 points). It was epic!

Comment: Did this turn out to be fun and did you play like this much?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replacement parts can be found from [Mayfair Games](http://mayfairgames.com/parts.php?game=55), although this will match your 4th Edition color pieces. (Older editions came in different colors). If you want [Seafarer's](http://mayfairgames.com/parts.php?game=59) , or other sets they have those too.

> **Settlers of Catan- Pieces** - Set 4 player -White Blue Red and Orange with Robber ( MFGP3061-41 ) Price: $12.00

If you wanted some approximate replacements, [PnP Productions](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/63183/print-play-productions-parts) has wooden ships (Seafarer's), wooden blocks (Knights & Cities, city walls), plastic hotels & houses (settlements/cities), and wooden cubes (roads?) in quite a few colors that differ from the original 4th Ed. colors.

Comment: Mayfair also sells theme sets to match up with the latest wooden edition of the game. These are called "Viking" pieces and come in the same range of colors in case you want a special set just for the larger board.

Comment: @TapanZee, I didn't know if they were interested in replacement parts for Seafarers, but mentioned the ships in the PnP Productions since that was on their list. But, it might make sense to add links to some off the other games.

Comment: Hey, googling various things led me to [this potentially awesome](http://www.spielmaterial.de/english4/start.php?catan_settler_single_components.php) site, but I don't have Euros, so it may just be something I keep in mind.

Comment: @Danielδ - If you pay by paypal, they should do the conversion for you.

Comment: On the other hand, they charge 20 EUR shipping, so unless I'm going for a very large quantity, it's not really worth it.  Otherwise, EUR$1 would cover all I'm missing.

Comment: @user1873 Sorry for the late reply. You can find viking parts at http://www.catanshop.com/Accessories-C22.aspx Mayfair also sells just the ships for one player unpainted at http://mayfairgames.com/goody.php?id=246 and full one player unpainted sets at http://mayfairgames.com/goody.php?id=244

Answer (score 5):

http://www.spielematerial.de/en/game-components/catan-all-about-the-settler-universe.html

Great website from Germany that sells all the Settlers playing pieces; many options ... you can buy sets of pieces or just the missing parts :).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of sellers on ebay that have replacement parts in a variety of colors, including a bunch that aren't part of the actual game (purple, pink, gold, etc).  A quick search there should turn up quite a few options.

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly more DIY approach, you can purchase square dowels from most craft stores that are the exact size of the roads in Catan.  Buy a dowel for around $2, cut it down to size, you have roads.  A slightly larger square down could be done for the settlements, then a larger round dowel could be cut down for cities.  You could also paint or color the pieces in any color you wanted, making the distinction easier than between sets of the same color with sharpie dots.  Just a thought.